# How to hide FPS numbers in bottom left of screen in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

How do I get rid of the numbers in the bottom left of the screen when I am making a cocos2d game? This is probably a newb question, but still.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a ShowFPS var in one of the files when you create the initial cocos project. But this should work from anywhere:

```
[[Director sharedDirector] setDisplayFPS:NO];
```

Comment: Where is it?? Your answer doesn't make sense

Comment: Sorry about that, comment got cut off.

Comment: It's in your app delegate class. in didFinishLaunching method.

Comment: For Cocos2d v3 you can do [CCDirector sharedDirector].displayStats = NO;

Answer (score 13):

if your app delegate.. Look for

```
    [director setDisplayFPS:YES];
```

change it to

```
    [director setDisplayFPS:NO];
```

or you can call this anywhere like the previous answer:

```
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector]setDisplayFPS:NO];
```

Answer (score 11):

Just a heads up for people checking this out at a later date (like me).  `setDisplayFPS` is deprecated now. Use `setDisplayStats` instead.

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDisplayStats:NO];
```

Answer (score 3):

To show it only when compiling for debug:

```
#if defined (DEBUG)
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDisplayFPS:NO];
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

in AppDelegate.cpp file, and the applicationDidFinishLaunching method

```
// turn on display FPS
pDirector->setDisplayStats(true);
```

change true to false

Answer (score 1):

for cocos2D 3.0

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDisplayStats:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

In appdelegate.m
after didfinishlaunchingoptions.

```
[startUpOptions setObject:@(NO) forKey:CCSetupShowDebugStats];
```

setObject:@NO (It is YES by default).